# How to use Shift+CapsLock+L to select text

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I used the following code to remap some key combinations. However, they do not work when pressed by other modifiers. For example, I want to select text using <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (just as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> does), but this does not work. What's wrong with it?

```
CapsLock::Send, {CTRLDOWN}{SHIFTDOWN}{SHIFTUP}{CTRLUP}{CTRLUP}
    return
!^CapsLock::CapsLock

CapsLock & j  :: Send  {Down}
CapsLock & k  :: Send {Up}
CapsLock & h  :: Send {Left}
CapsLock & l  :: Send {right}
CapsLock & p  :: Send {PGUP}
CapsLock & `; :: Send {PGDN}
CapsLock & ^  :: Send {home}
CapsLock & $  :: Send {end}
```

Comment: What does "they do not work when pressed by other modifiers" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See help topic on [Remapping Keys and Buttons](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm)

Add `{Blind}` as needed... I'm not sure the first two lines of code listed are necessary but I'm sure you can get it to work...

```
CapsLock & j  :: Send {Blind}{Down}
CapsLock & k  :: Send {Blind}{Up}
CapsLock & h  :: Send {Blind}{Left}
CapsLock & l  :: Send {Blind}{right}
```

Answer (score 0):

See help topic on [Hotkeys (Mouse, Joystick and Keyboard Shortcuts)](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm).

You may need to use the wildcard (*) in the hotkey definition to allow other modifiers.

Comment: Thanks. That did not help. Reading the doc, I see that `*` is not related to the issue.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do then.  The last edit to your post just shows hotkey definitions.